# Определенный формат текста в строке

Tags: c#, .net

в C# можно вот так форматировать числа:

```
long num = 12345678910;
Console.WriteLine(num.ToString("+# (###) ###-##-##")); // +1 (234) 567-89-10
```

Вопрос - можно ли так же делать с текстом? Т.е. надо чтобы текст занимал, например, 10 символов, вне зависимости от того, сколько их в переменной. Долгое гугление меня ни к чему не привело

```
string a = "text";
Console.WriteLine($"{a: ####}"); // это никак не меняет формат.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 10 символов

```
string a = "text";
Console.WriteLine($"{a,10}");  // "      text"
Console.WriteLine($"{a,-10}"); // "text      "
```

[Управление шириной поля и выравниванием в форматированных выражениях интерполяции](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation#how-to-control-the-field-width-and-alignment-of-the-formatted-interpolation-expression)

Еще есть методы `.PadLeft` и `.PadRight`, для них можно задать не только ширину строки для паддинга, но и символ, который будет использоваться как паддинг вместо пробела.